# ffmpeg rtsp stream to YouTube livestream not doing anything

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, youtube, rtsp, transcoding

I'm using C# to initiate ffmpeg. I've a onvif bridge server for a CCTV VMS and I'm building a application to enable the user to livestream any CCTV camera to YouTube.

The rtsp stream to the camera looks like this:

rtsp://onvif:bridge@localhost:554/live/xxxxx-xxxguidtocameraxxx-xxxxx

I'm new to ffmpeg and I'm using this arg:

-f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport udp -i {camerastreamurl} -tune zerolatency -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt + -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/{streamkey} -loglevel debug

It seems like ffmpeg isn't finding the camera stream, only the fake audio one. It just freezes.

This is the result of the debug log:

```
ffmpeg version N-91172-gebf85d3190 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 18.102 / 56. 18.102
  libavcodec     58. 19.104 / 58. 19.104
  libavformat    58. 17.100 / 58. 17.100
  libavdevice    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
  libavfilter     7. 24.100 /  7. 24.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'lavfi'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'anullsrc'.
Reading option '-rtsp_transport' ... matched as AVOption 'rtsp_transport' with argument 'udp'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'rtsp://onvif:bridge@localhost:554/live/41cf4f34-e137-4559-8278-47d912c64c5b'.
Reading option '-tune' ... matched as AVOption 'tune' with argument 'zerolatency'.
Reading option '-vcodec' ... matched as option 'vcodec' (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'libx264'.
Reading option '-pix_fmt' ... matched as option 'pix_fmt' (set pixel format) with argument '+'.
Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-c:a' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'aac'.
Reading option '-strict' ...Routing option strict to both codec and muxer layer
 matched as AVOption 'strict' with argument 'experimental'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'flv'.
Reading option 'rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxxxxxx' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url anullsrc.
Applying option f (force format) with argument lavfi.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: anullsrc.
detected 8 logical cores
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000027a34bad7c0] query_formats: 2 queried, 3 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
[Parsed_anullsrc_0 @ 0000027a34badb80] sample_rate:44100 channel_layout:'stereo' nb_samples:1024
[lavfi @ 0000027a34babc80] All info found
Input #0, lavfi, from 'anullsrc':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #0:0, 1, 1/44100: Audio: pcm_u8, 44100 Hz, stereo, u8, 705 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: input url rtsp://onvif:bridge@localhost:554/live/41cf4f34-e137-4559-8278-47d912c64c5b.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: rtsp://onvif:bridge@localhost:554/live/41cf4f34-e137-4559-8278-47d912c64c5b.
[tcp @ 0000027a34bb5980] No default whitelist set
```

Edit:
I'm getting this result with minimal args:
[image: ffmpeg result]

Comment: Wonder why do you have two `-i [parametervalue]` arguments. It is getting the wrong input. Have you tried `-f lavfi -i {camerastreamurl}  -rtsp_transport udp etc etc` ?

Comment: @bradbury9 That doesn't work. I got the args from multiple different articles with similar intentions as mine. 2 input sources are specified, the 1st one being "empty noise". If I remove the first input, I get the same text except "Input #0, lavfi, from 'anullsrc':" and the next 2 lines.

Comment: @bradbury9 check my post edit.

Comment: The whitelist message points to connectivity issues. Source: https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2016-March/031154.html

Comment: That's really strange. It works when I'm playing a networkstream in VLC. @bradbury9

Comment: besides checking network traffic and comparing VLC vs ffmpeg connections im out of ideas. Check the whitelist settings https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#Protocol-Options

Comment: I appreciate the effort :) @bradbury9

Comment: have you tried looking through wireshark/fiddler to see if you could get any traces of the error?

Beside that, you're having a `No default whitelist set` error... Could the problem be related to any kind of authentication mechanics?

Comment: I've no idea how to troubleshoot using that software since I've barely used it. According to the guys over at the official ffmpeg forums, the whitelist thing is nothing to worry about. @LoukMo